# How to insert text to class="block form-group"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a HTML-textbox that looks like this:

```
<div class="block form-group">
    <label for="translated-text"><b>Markerad Text</b>
    </label>
    <textarea class="width-100" id="translated-text" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Now i have data in a variable `content` within a function that i would like to get in to the textbox:

```
function getText(text) {
    var content = text.getValue();
}
```

When i click the button:

```
<div class="block" id="button-bar">
    <button class="green" id="insert-text">Markera</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: so do you want to get the value of the textfield in the content variable?

Comment: No i want the content in the variable "content" to be inserted to the textbox, when the user clicks the button. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the data of textarea with javascript you should use the followings;

```
<div class="block form-group">
  <label for="translated-text"><b>Markerad Text</b></label>
  <textarea class="width-100" id="translated-text" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<button class="green" id="insert-text" onclick="ReadData()" >Markera</button>

function ReadData()
{
    var data = $("#translated-text").val();
    alert(data);
}
```

You can get it by using id with javascript method.

if you want to get some values and put it to text area use these;

```
<div class="block form-group">
<label for="translated-text"><b>Markerad Text</b></label>
<textarea class="width-100" id="translated-text" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="exampleTxt" name="exampleTxt"/>
</div>
<button class="green" id="insert-text" onclick="ReadData()" >Markera</button>
<button class="green" id="insert-text" onclick="SendData()" >SendDataToTextArea</button>

function SendData()
{
 var value = $("#exampleTxt").val();
 $("#translated-text").val(value);
}
```

Comment: This works good to get the content in the textbox, and i will actually need it later, but first i need to add text to the textbox. 

Is it possible?

Comment: Yep it is possible. I updated my comment you can see over up ;)

Comment: That gives me another textbox, i would like to get data from a variable to be put into the already existing textbox

Comment: You can use hidden input types or send it from control by using ViewData property. After then the only thing that you have to do is the same as example.